# Exporting Excel 2016 sheets to png

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code that I cobbled together from different sources online that exports each sheet printable area as a png. If I run the VBA it outputs the files but as blank white pictures. If I put a stop in at line

```
chartobj.Chart.Paste
```

then it outputs the picture correctly.

I tried putting in a few loops or pauses but nothing works except for manual stopping the execution at that line.

```
Sub ExportToPNG()
' PNG Export Macro
' Change output = "C:\FOLDER\" to your folder path where you need the files saved
' Save Each Worksheet to a separate PNG file.

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
nm = ws.Name


Set sheet = ActiveSheet
output = "C:\FOLDER\" & nm & ".png"
zoom_coef = 100 / sheet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
Set area = sheet.Range(sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
Set chartobj = sheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, 
area.Height * zoom_coef)
chartobj.Chart.Paste
chartobj.Chart.Export output, "png"
chartobj.Delete

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI -- since you're doing `For each ws ...` and looping through, the `Set sheet = Activesheet` is superfluous.  Just use `ws.Parent...` or `ws.Range(ws.Pagesetup.PrintArea)`, etc.

Comment: I just ran this XL2010 and it worked perfectly whether or not I run step-by-step (F8) or all at once (F5).

Comment: Try sticking a `DoEvents` between the `Paste` and the `Export`, I guess

Comment: @Mat'sMug I tried the    DoEvents    but it still only outputs blank white pictures unless I stop it on the    Paste line . . .

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That is so strange, it only outputs blank white pictures for me without stopping it at the Paste line . . .

Comment: @Allison - A little inane, but how about a restart?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a need for this functionality and got the same issue when running full speed. After Paste the chart object was just white. However when single stepping in debug it worked all the time.

I tried a single call to DoEvents but no change. Added a loop with 1000 calls to DoEvents and Voila - it worked! Less than 1000 would probably work, but I did not bother to find the optimal safe number to use.

Also I changed the CopyPicture format from xlPrinter to xlScreen as the xlPrinter format seems to depend on which default printer you have.

```
Public Sub SavePlotsAsPng()
Dim pngfile As String
nm = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
nm = Split(nm, ".")(0)
pngfile = nm & "_" & Range("Start_Depth").Value & "_" & Range("End_Depth").Value & ".png"
zoom_coef = 1 '100 / ActiveSheet.ParentWindows(1).Zoom
Set area = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z59")
area.CopyPicture (xlScreen)
DoEvents
Set chartobj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
For i = 1 To 1000
    DoEvents
Next i
chartobj.Chart.Paste
chartobj.Chart.Export pngfile, "png"
chartobj.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: "[...] I did not bother to find the optimal safe number to use [DoEvents]" - The safe number to use `DoEvents` in succession is 1 (or infinitely as an event loop). If that doesn't solve the problem, then `DoEvents` is not the solution.